# Java - reverse sentences using Stacks

Tags: java, stack

I am attempting to create a method that accepts a string as an input and returns another string that reverses the order of each sentence in the input using Stacks. For example, if the user inputs "hi there. i like red." the outputted string should be "there hi. red like i.". The following program I have created works fine for only one sentence. How could i modify the method to recognize a period, and start the method over again? Currently, if I input "hi there", the output is "there hi", which is just fine. However, if I input "hi there. i like red.", the output is "red. like i there. hi". How can I modify this reverseSentence method to recognize periods and to start over for the next sentence? Any advise or tips will be very helpful.

```
//Reverses the order of words inside of sentences.

import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class reverse {

  //reverses the string using a stack
  private static String reverseSentence(String inputString) {

     String[] arrString = inputString.trim().split(Pattern.quote(" "));
     Stack stack = new Stack();

     for(String word : arrString) 
     {
       stack.push(word);
     }
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    while( !stack.isEmpty()) 
    {
      builder.append(stack.pop()).append(" ");
    }
    return builder.toString();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    Stack<String> stack = new Stack<String>();

    System.out.printf("Enter a sentence: ");
    String sentence = scanner.nextLine();

    if (sentence == null || sentence.length() == 0) {
      System.out.println("Invalid...");
      return;
    }

    String reverse = reverseSentence(sentence);
    System.out.printf("Reversed string using stack is : %s", reverse);


    while (!stack.isEmpty()) {
      System.out.print(stack.pop() + " ");
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before splitting the input at the space, trim it by period and run the logic inside your method in a for-loop for every sentence / splitted part you got earlier.

In your main-method, instead of calling reverseSentence:

```
String[] sentences = sentence.trim().split(Pattern.quote("."));
for (String toReverse : sentences) {
                            System.out.print(reverseSentece(toReverse));
}
```

I know this is not perfect, but I hope to give an idea of what I mean, because I am typing on my phone.

Answer (score 0):

Use the string split method.
`String[] sentences = sentence.split ("\\.");` maybe?

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches that come to my mind to achieve this:

1. First split the string by '.', giving you a list of sentences in the string. Apply your logic to every sentence. Output every reversed sentence separated by a period.
2. Use your current logic, but before adding any word to stack, check if the word's last character is a period. If it is, this means it is the end of a sentence. Pop the stack till empty and display contents. (This will display the inverted sentence till here) Continue with the next word.

Hope this helps!